# How to move textViews between layouts in Android?

Tags: android

I'm new to Android and I'm trying to make it so that when I click on a TextView it moves from its current LinearLayout to a new LinearLayout called 'letter1'.

I've looked around for ages but the only thing I can see that's close is 'setContentView' which just seems to crash my app. Code is below, could do with some help.

```
public class Question1 extends AppCompatActivity {
    LinearLayout letter1 = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.letter1);
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_question1);

        TextView letterL = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.letterL);
        letterL.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                setContentView(letter1);
            }
        });

        }
    }
```

Comment: Include your logs and error message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_question1);

        LinearLayout letter1 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.letter1);

        TextView letterL = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.letterL);
        letterL.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                letter1.addView(letterL);
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I had to add letterParent.removeView(letterL); in the onClick but it works perfectly now :).

Comment: Accept the answer then, regards